# AWS Lambda function to create / delete entries into WAF

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-js

I am trying to write a basic logic for creating WAF entries (that would block a ip address or set of ip addresses to enter) and later delete them.

i am currently doing this

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

const s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });
const waf = new aws.WAF({ apiVersion: '2015-08-24' });

class Police {
  constructor(maxHit=100, timeGap=(6*60*60*1000)) {
    this.maxHit = maxHit;
    this.timeGap = timeGap;
    this.lastBailCheck = Date.now();
    this.hitMap = {};
  }
  static bail(ip){
    // TODO bail this ip by removing entry into waf
  }
  static jail(ip){
    // TODO jail this ip by adding entry from waf
  }
  checkBail(){
    var nowDate = Date.now();
    if((nowDate - this.lastBailCheck) > this.timeGap){
      this.lastBailCheck = nowDate;
      this.prevMap = this.hitMap;
      this.hitMap = {};
      this.scanAndBail();
    }
  }
  scanAndBail(){
    Object.keys(this.prevMap).forEach(Police.bail);
    delete this.prevMap;
  }
  watch(ip){
    this.hitMap[ip] = (this.hitMap[ip] || 0) + 1;
    if(this.maxHit < this.hitMap[ip]){
      Police.jail(ip);
    }
    this.checkBail();
  }
}

const police = new Police();

function forOneLogLine(line){
  if(typeof line === 'string') {
    police.watch(line.split(' ')[3]);
  }
}
```

So here i want to fill code for `jail` and `bail` (to block / free a ip address or a set of addresses)

I went through this [AWS nodejs docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/WAF.html) . But it was so confusing how to implement it. And more specifically how to optimally implement it.
I was looking for just two APIs, one that i would pass ip address and that would block that, and another to free that.

I have a few basic question from above docs

1. How do i pass ip address? and in which API?
2. Does `aws.WAF` automatically groups a set of ip addresses into IPSets?
3. Does `aws.WAF` also keeps the hit counts, something similar i am doing in class `Police` ?
4. Do i need to fetch `ChangeToken` for **every** `IPaddress` that i am going to add/remove into block list? Or can i have it once and use that forever?

I would be glad to have a sample code (preferably in javascript) for this exact requirement.
I would be delighted if i get my `jail` and `bail` code filled.

Answer (score 0):

AWS has a tutorial on [Blocking IPs That Exceed Request Limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/tutorials-rate-based-blocking.html), including [sample Python code](https://s3.amazonaws.com/awswaf.us-east-1/waf-reactive-blacklist/parser.zip) which you might find helpful in writing the equivalent JavaScript code to call [updateIPSet](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/WAF.html#updateIPSet-property) (for both inserting and deleting IP sets).

Comment: okay.. that's good.. but i do not want to create a cloud formation stack.. isn't that possible without stack? I mean, i am just making updates to WAF entries.. where does stack comes in between? i had already gone through the tutorial.. and tried to do all at my own, without using a stack(template). Even the tutorial says, lamda function makes an entry to WAF.. i am just doing the same.. with purely simple logic..

Comment: Right, no need for CloudFormation here. I'd expect you to be able to do this via the JavaScript SDK. Is the sample Python Lambda code not helpful?

Comment: it was certainly helpful.. Getting some idea what is happening.. but just struggling with where ip set is coming from and little bit with python.. very new to python